# WordPress подключение js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, веб-программирование

Я подключаю скрипты через function.php

```
function wp_add_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', ['jquery']);
wp_enqueue_script( 'loadport', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/loadport.js', ['jquery']);
wp_enqueue_script( 'materialize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/materialize.min.js', ['jquery'] );
wp_enqueue_script( 'myjs',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myjs.js', ['jquery'] );
//    wp_enqueue_script( 'json', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/portfolio.json', ['jquery']);
}add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_add_scripts');
function jquery_init() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}}add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_init');'
```

Скрипты подключаются вроде вполне нормально

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

Но при этом выдаётся ошибка и скрипты абсолютно не работают. Не могу понять почему. (тут же выше html код с подключенными скриптами)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе же ошибка ясно говорит "чувак не могу прочитать свойство `event` у **не** существующего объекта"
Это скорее всего связано с тем что во время работы скрипта DOM дерево еще не готово. 
Используй аргумент у функции `wp_enqueue_script` для подключения скрипта перед закрывающимся `</body>` точнее там где вызывается тег шаблона `wp_footer()`.
Вот [здесь](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script) можно почитать подробнее.

Это раз.
Во вторых походу шрифты не подключились, а скрипты с ними работают. Проверь это.

Comment: Сделал всё как написано, шрифты подключил, всё что не надо убрал. Но ошибка materialize.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined  осталась. Всё находится в футере, после jquery. В чем ещё может быть проблема?

Comment: так на вскидку сказать не могу, может проблема в очередности подключения и в зависимостях скриптов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблема решилась, не поверите как, просто я перезалил файл materialize.min.js в проект и всё исправилось, как он мог повредится ума не приложу, тк я его не трогал.